# Updated: How can I insert a script at a specific position in the page of a NextJS app?

Tags: javascript, next.js, embedding

I am trying to get a script embedding onto my next.js application, however it is at the end of the page, instead of where I place it.

I already took the solution mentioned in How to precisely control where script tag is inserted using Next Script, but the issue still persists. I also tried to embed it with the application script method described here https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script, but I get the same result.

My helloworld.tsx in pages looks like this:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import Script from 'next/script'

export const HelloWorld = () => {

    const containerRef = useRef(null)

    function moveScript() {
        containerRef.current.appendChild(this)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <p>This goes before the embedding</p>
            <div ref={containerRef} id="script-container">
                <Script strategy="lazyOnload" id="asciicast-aMFGH8jU7O7uo94YZyWJEZtnO" type="text/javascript" src="https://asciinema.org/a/aMFGH8jU7O7uo94YZyWJEZtnO.js" async onLoad={moveScript}/>
            </div>
            <p>This goes after the embedding <br /></p>
        </>
    );
};
export default HelloWorld;
```

On the resulting page the embedding is at the bottom of the page, however I expect it to be between the two paragraph.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use an useEffect to load the script, and then append it?
Since useEffect runs after the render of the component, you could either:

[1] use it to load the script in it (assuring that the script load goes after the component rendering), or

[2] use it afterwards to move (append) the script to the specific ref. I can't test your code right now, but I'm pretty sure that might help you solve the problem you're having.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I got it running with useEffect as follows:

export const HelloWorld = () => {

    const containerRef = useRef(null)

    useEffect(()=>{
        const script = document.createElement('script')
        script.src=scriptpath,
        containerRef.current.appendChild(script)
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <p>Foo</p>
            <div style={{maxWidth:'650px'}} ref={containerRef}>
            </div>
            <p>Bar <br /></p>
        </>
    );
};

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the next/script  attribute to load a script in any page, this worked for me.